# Nhibernate row level locking

Tags: nhibernate, session, transactions

How can i implement locking of a record in Nhibernate.
I have tried

1. transactions with isolation level and
2. session locking.

Which approach is better for row level locking?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options given aren't mutually exclusive. You need the transaction with some suitable isolation level specified otherwise you will not have any locks at all. If you by "session locking" mean calling session.Lock(), this is a way to take or upgrade a lock within a preexisting transaction.

If you by "transaction with isolation level" specifically means "serializable isolation level", a possible drawback is that it might take more locks than required since it will put some lock on all read rows.

Comment: Session.Lock(obj,Lockmode.Upgrade) locks all the rows in my table.why is it so?

Comment: It surprises me that it locks all rows in the table. (How have you verified that?)

Comment: *DTO.COMPANY comp;
        UoW = new UnitOfWork().UOW();
        IRepository.IFetchEntityWithLock<DTO.COMPANY> dal1 = new                                                                  DepInjector.clsEntityDepContainer<DTO.COMPANY>().FetchWithLock(); 
 dal1.Session = UoW.Session;
 comp = dal1.IFetchEntityWithLock("001");
 //UoW.Commit;*


***FetchWithLock****

return POSSession.Get<TEntity>(entId,LockMode.UpgradeNoWait);

****FetchWithLock****

Since I have not committed the transaction the record is locked.
Now i am not able to update other records in a different session .